# Too late to claim BCH and BTG

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash

I recently came back in from the crypto wilderness and heard about the BCH (Bitcoin Cash)and BTG (Bitcoin Gold), which were given out when the currency forked. I have 2 BTC's which I have started to update.

I was wondering if it's too late to claim the BTG and BCH?

Comment: Do you own the private key(s) of the address (es) you have the 2 btc on? And where these coins (or some other amount) located on those addresses the minute before the forks happened?

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. So I have the backup of the wallet from  22nd dec 2017 and 27th march 2014. What I've done is using the current wallet (which is the same as the backup wallets, just more recent) exported private key from the desktop client and then imported the private key into a BCH wallet, but nothing is showing up. Am i missing something

Comment: I cannot tell without knowing your btc address. Btw, I suspect the key part that you may be missing is a correct assumption about wether these wallet and backups are really the same. And the balance of those addresses on the minute before the fork. These are things you can easily check on a blockexplorer

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek Hi Christian, I'll google how to use block explorer, unless you have time to guide me through it or know of a good tutorial, in the meantime I can provide you my btc addresss if that helps? 16BawiLNCZ8BUsF4kuvte27Tv7Zgjt8Yia

Comment: Just checked block explorer, not a complicated as I had feared :)  No transactions have been made on that address, so would my address have changed? If I restore an old wallet will that have retained the original address?

Comment: Yes it will. An address does not change. You just had different addresses in the wallets you had and have.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek Thanks Christian, I'll restore an older wallet and see what happens. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no deadline to claim these forks. If you have access to the private keys of the addresses that owned Bitcoin during these forks, you own those coins too.

Answer (score -1):

No, its not too late. if both coins were held before the fork, then you can claim them.